# How not to repeat math operations two times in calculator app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have made a simple calculator in "Kotlin" using an android studio
the problem I got and I don't have a way to fix it is how not to repeat the math operations after typing a number .. Perhaps because I am new to the world of Android application development and I do not know the way I should avoid this problem.

Example of what I mean, He entered addition/subtraction twice:

[image]

My codes :
**Main.kt**

```
  package com.iosmostafa.calculator
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.util.Log
    import com.iosmostafa.calculator.R
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    import net.objecthunter.exp4j.ExpressionBuilder
    
    class Main : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            //Numbers
            tvOne.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("1", true) }
            tvTwo.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("2", true) }
            tvThree.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("3", true) }
            tvFour.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("4", true) }
            tvFive.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("5", true) }
            tvSix.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("6", true) }
            tvSeven.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("7", true) }
            tvEight.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("8", true) }
            tvNine.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("9", true) }
            tvZero.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("0", true) }
            tvDot.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion(".", true) }
    
    
    
            //Operators
            tvPlus.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("+", false) }
            tvMinus.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("-", false) }
            tvMul.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("*", false) }
            tvDivide.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("/", false) }
            tvOpen.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion("(", false) }
            tvClose.setOnClickListener { appendOnExpresstion(")", false) }
            tvNew1.setOnClickListener{(appendOnExpresstion("%",false))}
    
            tvClear.setOnClickListener {
                tvExpression.text = ""
                tvResult.text = ""
            }
    
            tvBack.setOnClickListener {
                val string = tvExpression.text.toString()
                if(string.isNotEmpty()){
                    tvExpression.text = string.substring(0,string.length-1)
                }
                tvResult.text = ""
            }
    
    
    
            tvEquals.setOnClickListener {
                try {
    
                    val expression = ExpressionBuilder(tvExpression.text.toString()).build()
                    val result = expression.evaluate()
                    val longResult = result.toLong()
                    if(result == longResult.toDouble())
                        tvResult.text = longResult.toString()
                    else
                        tvResult.text = result.toString()
    
                }catch (e:Exception){
                    Log.d("Exception"," message : " + e.message )
                }
            }
    
    
        }
    
        fun appendOnExpresstion(string: String, canClear: Boolean) {
    
            if(tvResult.text.isNotEmpty()){
                tvExpression.text = ""
            }
    
            if (canClear) {
                tvResult.text = ""
                tvExpression.append(string)
            } else {
                tvExpression.append(tvResult.text)
                tvExpression.append(string)
                tvResult.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvExpression"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80sp"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/numberButton"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/numberButton"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvClear"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="حذف" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOpen"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="(" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvClose"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text=")" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNew1"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="%" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDivide"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="/" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSeven"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEight"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="8" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNine"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="9" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMul"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="X" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFour"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFive"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSix"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="6" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMinus"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="-" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOne"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTwo"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvThree"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPlus"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="+" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDot"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvZero"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:text="0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tvBack"
                style="@style/NumberButtonStyle"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/backspace" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEquals"
                style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
                android:text="=" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You don't want to add two operators next to each other You have to check if last character is the operator. It will look something like this:

```
fun appendOnExpresstion(string: String, canClear: Boolean)
{
    if (tvResult.text.isNotEmpty())
    {
        tvExpression.text = ""
    }
    if (canClear)
    {
        tvResult.text = ""
        tvExpression.append(string)
    }
    else
    {
        if (tvExpression.text.lastOrNull() !in arrayOf('+', '-', '*', '/')) // You are adding operator so You have to check if last char is oparetor
        {
            tvExpression.append(tvResult.text)
            tvExpression.append(string)
        }
        tvResult.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Big thanx for you can you tell me what is " lastOrNull " ( why we use it here) mean?

Comment: `lastOrNull` is a method that will return last character in string or null if string is empty

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

first param: it is the String that is pass

second param: it is the number of time that reapeat something characters

```
fun removeConsecutiveCharactersInString(str: String, maxConsecutiveAllowedCount: Int)
{
val builder = StringBuilder(str)

var i = 0

while (i < builder.length) {

    var foundCount = 0

    for (j in i - 1 downTo 0) {

        if (lowerCasedChar(builder[i]) == lowerCasedChar(builder[j])) {

            foundCount++

            if (foundCount >= maxConsecutiveAllowedCount) {

                builder.deleteCharAt(i)

                i--

                break

            }
        } else {

            break

        }
    }

    i++
}

return builder.toString()
```

}